# React Native - Is using Immer.js and SetState together a problem?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, immutability, immer.js

Yesterday I had a behaviour that I don't understand by using Immer.js and setState together. I was using a setState (in a bad way, by the way) when fetching my data and this fetch was called at each endReached of my SectionList.

This setState looked like this:

```
this.setState((prev) => {
    let sections = prev.sections

    /* Extract alive topics from "topics"(array retrieved from fetch)*/
    let topicsSection1 = topics.filter((card) => !card.states.is_killed)

    /* Extract killed topics from "topics"(array retrieved from fetch)*/
    let topicsSection2 = topics.filter((card) => card.states.is_killed)

    if (sections[0] && sections[0].data)
    sections[0].data = positionExtracted > 1 ? sections[0].data.concat(...topicsSection1) : topicsSection1

    if (sections[1] && sections[0].data)
    sections[1].data  = positionExtracted > 1 ? sections[1].data.concat(...topicsSection2) : topicsSection2

    return {
        sections: sections,
        position: response.position,
        lastPage: response.laftPage
    }
})
```

and everything worked just fine.

However, I have a function that is called when you press on the topic, and it changes the "opened" value of the topic in the data array to indicate to the list that "this topic" is open.
This function calls the "produce" function of Immer.js

And this function looks like this:

```
_onPressTopic = (id_card) => {
    this.setState(produce((draft) => {
        if (draft.sections[0] && draft.sections[0].data)
            draft.sections[0].data = draft.sections[0].data.map((item) => {
                if (item.id === id_card)
                    item.opened = !item.opened
                return item
            })
        if (draft.sections[1] && draft.sections[1].data)
            draft.sections[1].data = draft.sections[1].data.map((item) => {
                if (item.id === id_card)
                    item.opened = !item.opened
                return item
            })
    }))
}
```

**MY PROBLEM IS:**

If I open a topic and then my list data goes through this function, then when an endReached is called again, either I get an error "This object is not expensive", or my list data is not modified at all. And if instead of my first setState, I use a produce from Immer, everything works again.

What I don't understand is: Why does everything work perfectly if I only use Immer.js or just SetState, but as soon as I try to use both together, they don't seem to get along?

Thank you for your answers,

I hope I made it clear !

Viktor